# Assert.Pass made me out of loop. unable to generate out come

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I am automating a Web application using C#, VSTS2010, Nunit and .Resx file as data source.
able to pick the data successfully from Resource file. while generating results, upon using Assert.Pass("") it made me out of loop if passed. No idea how to produce the outcome and where ? Please assist me.

```
    foreach (string from1 in from)
            {
                foreach (string to1 in To)
                {
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(www.xyz.com);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbFrom")).Clear();
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbFrom")).SendKeys(from1);
                     driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbTo")).Clear();
                     driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbTo")).SendKeys(to1);
             if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("trAirLines")).Text.Contains("Air Canada"))
                    {
                       Assert.Pass("Air Canada Results are available")
                    }
         else
               {
                   Assert.Fail("AC not found")
               }
                }
```

all iteration get completed when I remove Assert statement else it get failed when it become pass

Comment: Do you mean, you have a loop whose inner body calls `Assert.Pass`? `Assert.Pass()` will end the test immediately as it raises an Exception. Could you provide some code, please?

Comment: Please find the above code

Answer (score 0):

You must not call `Assert.Pass()`. This will abort the execution of the test immediately. So `Assert.Fail()` does.

I think the best thing you can get along is:

```
foreach (string from1 in from)
{
    foreach (string to1 in To)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(www.xyz.com);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbFrom")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbFrom")).SendKeys(from1);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbTo")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbTo")).SendKeys(to1);

        var infoElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("trAirLines"));
        Assert.That(infoElement.Text, Is.StringContaining("Air Canada"));
    }
}
```

The `Assert.That ... Is.StringContaining` checks whether the text of the referenced element contains `"Air Canada"`. The test will now fail on the first element that does not fulfill this assertion - otherwise pass obviously.